# From Notes View, open XPiNC in different nsf application

Tags: xpages

I have several Notes Applications using traditional Notes Views with XPiNC pages as forms where there is an advantage over a Notes Form and traditional Notes Forms where there isn't any advantage or need to change, everything works very well.

I now need to develop my existing applications further and use the business logic, managed beans, XPages, Custom Controls etc in a different Notes nsf, but  I would like to stick with the existing Notes Views for functionality and speed wise as they appear far superior than any alternative outside traditional Notes and I would like to continue to use XPiNC so everything is available in the Notes Client for the users.

Is there a good way to, double click on a Notes View record, open an XPiNC page in a different application which can pull its data from the View record using managed beans rather than a Document data source. I have considered associating a blank XPage to the Form in the Views application and embed a second XPage from the bus logic application inside it, as I think you can only 'Display XPage instead of form' in the same application,  or on open the XPage associated with the form, automatically open a second XPage in the business logic nsf. I am not sure how I would get the document reference across and it all seems a little messy.

Any direction or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Off my head: dig into the documentation for composite applications. When you render your standard view using the composite (like the mail template) you can associate other events and use the wiring to trigger anything including an XPage